# NameError: name 'tabula' is not defined in python

Tags: python, dataframe, tabula

I am trying to extract only tables from pdf using tabula package and writing the output into csv,
Unfortunately, the below code gives me an error as "NameError: name 'tabula' is not defined"

How to fix this issue

**Code**:

```
!pip install tabula-py
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabula.io import read_pdf
file = r"url"
df = read_pdf(file, pages='all')
tabula.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Error:**

```
"NameError: name 'tabula' is not defined"
```

Comment: This is not causing the `NameError` but it is an issue: `from tabula.io import read_pdf` is clobbering `from tabula import read_pdf`. Each of these functions is assigned the same name in the current scope. You should figure out which one you want and only import it. As a general rule, don't import different things under the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an explanation. Every time you use `from module import function` it will take the function, not the entire library and the functions, so if you want to use that `tabula.to_csv()` function, you will need to import the whole library, using `import tabula`.

Other Method:
You can use `to_csv()` and import it with `from tabula import to_csv`

Comment: I am getting the error while "from tabula import to_csv" : cannot import name 'to_csv' from 'tabula' (C:\Users\userid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\__init__.py)

Comment: Oh, it means there is no function named to_csv in the tabula module, you can take a look at the tabula article or you can use the first method instead

Answer (score -1):

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabula.io import read_pdf
file = r"url"
df = read_pdf(file, pages='all')
tabula.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8') # from tabula import to_csv
```

You using the method but not imported so, it's giving this error

Comment: In official documentation says "tabula.convert_into("test.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')", but the same is not working for me, and it gives me the same error "NameError: name 'tabula' is not defined"

Comment: Also, I am able to get the output by calling "df", but help me how to write the same output into CSV